# How could I provide my own ticks array into chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

I want to provide my own array of ticks into the chart.js
Unfortunately there is only callback of "afterwork" on ticks provided.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `afterBuildTicks` callback on the scale:

```js
new Chart('my-chart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Data',
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      borderColor: '#1f77b4'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        afterBuildTicks: scale => {
          scale.ticks = [{
              value: 55
            },{
              value: 60
            },
            {
              value: 65
            },
            {
              value: 70
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="my-chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: LeeLenalee thank you. Unfortunately I've fall into RangeError: minimumFractionDigits value is out of range.
it seems I need to make" tickFormatter " function on each value. How this can be done in this snippet?

Comment: x: {
                    afterBuildTicks: scale => {
                        scale.ticks = tickArrayXAxis.map(item => 'value: ' + item)
                    },  anyway there is RangeError